# Real world applications of Ramsey Theory concerning friends and strangers

Tags: graph-theory

The classical problem in Ramsey theory is the party problem, which asks the minimum number of guests  that must be invited so that at least `m` will know each other (i.e., there exists a clique of order `m`) or at least `n` will not know each other (i.e., there exists an independent set of order `n`). Here, `R(m,n)` is called a Ramsey number.

See on [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyTheory.html) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers).

There seems to be a slew of research in the field. What are some real world applications? For example, I read in one place that circuit/network routing would be a good one. But how why is that? Does anyone know of any other real world applications?

Comment: ps: reminder that cstheory is a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this.

Answer (score 2):

A course I'm currently taking from Bill Gasarch is called: Ramsey Theory and Its 'Applications' -- the quotes are in the official course title. Interpret that as you wish. >_>

Here is a link to the course website (with lecture notes): http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/858/S13/S13.html

Here is a link to Bill's "Apps of Ramsey Theory" page: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/ramsey/ramsey.html

The latter link is very likely the most complete collection of information for the question you're asking.

Comment: Daniel, would you mind moving this answer to the other  question?

Comment: Sure -- And in fact, checking the other question, there's already a link to the Apps of Ramsey Theory page. I'll add the course link to it.